# Complex Structure on S^6 using Stereographic projection. Why does not work?

Tags: complex-geometry, spheres, stereographic-projections

Consider $S^6$ and do a Stereographic projection over $\mathbb{R}^6$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection). Give to $\mathbb{R}^6$ the natural complex structure, so it is $\mathbb{C}^3$, and push back the complex structure of $\mathbb{C}^3$ on the sphere.
Actually, repeat unless you cover the whole sphere with this structure.

As far as I know, there are no known integrable complex structure on $S^6$, so my question is: why the push back of $\mathbb{C}^3$ does not work?

Thank you.

Comment: You will get a complex structure on $S^6$ minus a point and then what?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I wrote "repeat unless you cover the whole sphere", meaning you take more chart (at least 2) to cover also the "north pole".

Comment: Then I suggest you compute the transition map and see why it is not holomorphic. The onus is on you to write details of your supposed argument.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$While your idea does define a holomorphic structure on the complement of a point, that structure does not extend over the point at infinity.

To define a holomorphic structure on $S^{6}$, we need a collection $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ of open sets covering $S^{6}$ and for each open set a homeomorphism $\phi_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha} \to \Cpx^{3}$ such that on each overlap $\phi_{\beta}(U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta})$, the mapping $\phi_{\alpha} \circ \phi_{\beta}^{-1}$ is a biholomorphism of open subsets of $\Cpx^{3}$. This compatibility is the "hard part".

On the two-sphere $S^{2}$, incidentally, stereographic projections from the north and south poles don't have this property, either; the overlap map is inversion in the unit circle, i.e., $z \mapsto 1/\bar{z}$. But if we replace stereographic projection from the south pole by its complex conjugate, then we've covered $S^{2}$ by two open sets, and the overlap map is $z \mapsto 1/z$, which is a biholomorphism of the set of non-zero compex numbers.

Comment: @AndrewDHwang Why the functions on the overlap are not biholomorphics ? can you provide an explicit computation?